# ¿Cómo consumir un WebSocket API desde Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, api, websocket, blockchain

Estoy realizando una aplicación que debe de consumir un `WebSocket API` de `blockchain.info`, esto permitirá que cuando se genere una transacción en mi cuanta se pueda guardar en mi base de datos. El problema es que no sé cómo consumir esta `WebSocket API` desde laravel 5.5, si alguien sabe estaré muy agradecido.

https://blockchain.info/api/api_websocket

Comment: En el mismo enlace que pones hay un enlace a un ejemplo http://websocket.org/echo.html

Comment: No creo que el problema sea Laravel sino el soporte de php para web socket.

Comment: si, eso veo, solo que el enlace es para consumir desde un cliente, yo lo necesito consumir desde el servidor, de igual forma veo que tengo que usar node.js,  muchas gracias.